# c++ operator overloading error. (most probably some syntax error)

Tags: c++, class, pointers, overloading, operator-keyword

I am new to operator overloading and am experiencing a weird error. The question asks that input two polynomials and then store their sum in a third object. The class myPolynomial contains 3 private variables i.e "float* degreeArray", "float* coeffArray" and "int terms".

In the main function i have the following code:

```
myPolynomial p4;

    p4 =  p1 + p2;
    p4.Print();
```

The plus operator function does its work correctly. Here it is:

```
myPolynomial myPolynomial::operator + (myPolynomial &obj) 
{
    int size = 2*terms;
    float arr[size];
    float arr2[size];
    myPolynomial temp(arr,arr2,size);

    int tempIndex = 0;

    bool found;

    for (int i=0;i<terms;i++)
    {
        found = false;
        for (int j=0; j<terms ;j++)
        {
            if (degreeArray[i] == obj.degreeArray[j])
            {
                found = true;

                temp.coeffArray[tempIndex] = coeffArray[i] + obj.coeffArray[j];
                temp.degreeArray[tempIndex] = degreeArray[i];
                tempIndex++;
            }

        }
        if (found == false)
        {
            temp.coeffArray[tempIndex] = coeffArray[i];
            temp.degreeArray[tempIndex] = degreeArray[i];
            tempIndex++;
        }
    }

    int tempSize = tempIndex;
    bool check;

    for (int i=0;i<obj.terms;i++)
    {
        check = false;
        for (int j = 0; j<tempSize ;j++)
        {
            if (obj.degreeArray[i]==temp.degreeArray[j])
            {
                check = true;               
            }
        }
        if (check == false)
        {
            temp.degreeArray[tempIndex] = obj.degreeArray[i];
            temp.coeffArray[tempIndex] = obj.coeffArray[i];
            tempIndex++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"tempIndex = "<<tempIndex<<endl;
    //checking values inside temp
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    for (int i = 0;i<tempIndex;i++)
    {
        cout<<temp.degreeArray[i]<<" ";

    }
    cout<<endl;
    for (int i = 0;i<tempIndex;i++)
    {
        cout<<temp.coeffArray[i]<<" ";

    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;

    temp.terms = tempIndex;
    return temp;
```

Next is the assignment operator overloading function which is correctly able to take the object from plus operator function and copy that to the class's primary object (i.e p4). However, it is unable to correctly return the object back for further use like Print() etc.

Here is the code:

```
myPolynomial& myPolynomial::operator = (const myPolynomial &obj)  
{

    terms = obj.terms; 
    degreeArray = new float [terms];
    coeffArray = new float [terms];

    cout<<terms;

    for (int i = 0; i<terms; i++)
    {
        degreeArray[i] = obj.degreeArray[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<terms; i++)
    {
        coeffArray[i] = obj.coeffArray[i];
    }
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;

    for (int i=0;i<terms;i++)
    {
        cout<<coeffArray[i]<<" ";
    }

    cout<<endl; 
    for (int i=0;i<terms;i++)
    {
        cout<<degreeArray[i]<<" ";
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Now, back to int main(), if i write myPolynomial p4() which means i am calling the default constructor than a weird error message comes that i am unable to understand.

It says:

[Error] cannot convert 'myPolynomial' to 'myPolynomial()' in assignment

If i write myPolynomial p4; then the code executes but gives an error during execution. The code executes till the assignment operator function i.e if i output something in this area then that works.

Lastly, if i use a parametrized constructor then the code runs correctly. However, i cannot do this since i don't know the "terms" of the new object "p4" before adding the terms of the previous two objects "p1 and p2".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `myPolynomial p4();` is a function declaration, like `int foo();`. If you want to call the default constructor, remove `()`.

Comment: Or if you want value initialization, `myPolynomial p4{}`.

Comment: Ok thanks for this info. But writing p4 alone gives an error during execution.

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: No, you will find that your plus operator overload does not work correctly. Try doing a `p1 + p2 + p3`, and see what happens. Hint: nothing. It won't even compile. As far as your compilation error, run a google search on "most vexing parse".

Comment: The problem with `myPolynomial p4()` is an example of the "most vexing parse" - something that most programmers interpret as a variable declaration, but the language rules (and therefore compilers) adamantly treat as a function declaration.   Compilers tend to win the argument.    If the declaration is changed to `myPolynominal p4` and gives a run time error then, odds are, there is some other problem in the code (e.g. invalid operation on a pointer).

Comment: A pedantic hint that has nothing to do with your problem: replace <aBoolean> == false by !<aBoolean>

Comment: `float arr[size];
    float arr2[size];
    myPolynomial temp(arr,arr2,size);` -- don't tell me that your `myPolynomial` expects these auto-storage variables to exist for the duration of its own existence. Ummm, no, that's not going to happen.

Comment: Why you need operator overloading? Keep it simple.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I just check and it works for p1 + p2 + p3. I don't know exactly what the problem was but my code works now. One thing i remember doing is that initially in the paramteried constructor i wrote: terms = 4; instead of terms = t (the parameter that was passed into the parametrized constructor).

Comment: No, it cannot possibly work for `p1+p2+p3` using the definition of the `+` operator given in the question. C++ does not work this way. mutable references do not bound to temporaries. Therefore, your actual code must be different from the code shown in the question, so everyone is wasting their time here.